# Can Two separate Application share their resources like database?

Tags: android

I have two separate Application in the same work space Now can i use resourses like.. database of one application in another??
please help me out..

Comment: ?!@$.. By `work space` do you mean the one in eclipse? and do you want to access the same database across these two applications? *Yes*, why not? I don't think there is any limitation such as a database can be accessed by only one application!! The usual way is to use a `content provider`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has several issues regarding security and permissions but yes it is possible, as if you are android user some application asks to get your contact list details? How do they get into your phonebook application and get details from there? got a clue?

now follow this link it may help you

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/security.html

Be ethical,

Happy Coding

Answer (score 2):

The normal way of sharing data like that between applications would be to use a ContentProvider to proxy the database and make it available in a managed way.

Answer (score 1):

Yes they can, multiple applications with the same sharedUserId in the manifest, and signed with the same key, can access each other resources.

Take a look at this links:

http://androidboss.com/androids-shareduserid/

http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.com/2009/06/controlling-application-separation.html

Comment: Google strongly discourages the use of `sharedUserId`. Also, if your app is already on the Market, you can no longer use `sharedUserId` without breaking 100% of the users who upgrade their apps to your new `sharedUserId` version.

Comment: If an app is already on the market you can't, that's true, you should force them to uninstall the app and install the new one.. Using content providers you cannot restrict access to it only to your applications without using, again, the same sharedUserId.. If you don't care about restricting access to your shared content provider then just go with it!

Comment: Or maybe there is and I missed it =) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6120025/how-to-restrict-content-provider-data-across-applications