# Tiered subscription across apps

Tags: android, in-app-billing, in-app-subscription

Is it possible to have a tiered subscription model in android that works across apps? I have 3 apps A,B and C which all require a subscription in order to be used. If I have a subscription to A, I can use A but not B or C . If I have a subscription to B, I can use B and A but not C. And If I have a subscription to C I can use all the apps. In other words the levels are C>B>A.

I have tried using the android billing library to access subscriptions of the A app from the B app but without success.

The [in app subscriptions documentation](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_subscriptions.html) says :

> You can implement your own solution for sharing subscriptions across as many different apps or products as you want. For example, you could sell a subscription that gives a subscriber access to an entire collection of apps, games, or other content for a monthly or annual fee. To implement this solution, you could add your own business logic to your app to determine whether the user has already purchased a given subscription and if so, allow access to your content.

Is it possible to set this up using only the android in-app billing API from inside the apps? Has this been set up before using Google Play to handle purchases and a backend to keep track of subscriptions? The main question is: Is it possible to access information from one app about a subscription on another app that I manage?

Comment: Please clarify if you have your own server handling billing/in-app purchases or you are trying to do this without.

Comment: I was trying to do it without the backend, but I'm fairly sure it can only be done with the backend: When a user has bought a subscription, the receipt/information should be sent to the backend and distributed to the other apps as required.

Answer (score 1):

One option would have to have each app provide a [Content Provider](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) where each app would look for the other apps and confirm subscription state.

Also see:
[How to restrict content provider data across applications](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6120025/295004)

A downside is that each app would need to be installed on device. If it was server based, someone could buy subscription to app C on one device and with the same subscriber identity have app B and app A on a different device.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Morrison Chang. I have decided the tiered subscription is too difficult to implement in the time I have. I may update this question with the solution I use in the future.