# Updating app from another app

Tags: android, updates

I have a app named `com.example.free`. and when user download the app named `com.example.paid` from play store which is 4 to 5 KB, it must enable free apps paid features. Can anyone has solution for this?

**EDIT:**
you can see this feature in CamScanner app. but how they do it. Without using Content Provider.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a reverse engineering service. What makes you think the CamScanner app isn't using a Content Provider or more likely a server to authenticate purchases (as it appears to have a subscription option)

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be the unlocking app provide a [Content Provider](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) where each client app would look to and confirm purchase.

Also see:
[How to restrict content provider data across applications](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6120025/295004)

Note that using a server for providing 'unlock' feature keys improves the anti-piracy as both the unlocking app and the client app can be accessed on rooted devices.

Answer (score 0):

A common and probably better solution to enable paid app features is to implement an in-app purchase. Barring that, you could try getting a list of the currently installed packages on the device and check for your paid app. For example:

```
List<PackageInfo> packages = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);
for (PackageInfo packageInfo : packages) {
    if (packageInfo.packageName.equals("com.example.paid")) {
        // Unlock paid features
    }
}
```